# Reading JSON tree structure into custom javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, tree

I have a JSON string:

```
{ "a1": "root", 
  "a2": "root data", 
  "children": [
    { "a1": "child 1", 
      "a2": "child 1 data", 
      "children": []
    }, 
    { "a1": "child 2", 
      "a2": "child 2 data", 
      "children": [
        { "a1": "child 3", 
          "a2": "child 3 data", 
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to read this JSON tree structured string into a JavaScript object. I want the class definition of the JavaScript object to be as follows:

```
function MyNode(){
    this.a1 = ""
    this.a2 = ""
    this.children = []
}
```

Basically after reading the JSON data structure I would like a have an instance of type `MyNode` which has the parameters `a1` `a2` and `children`, where `children` or the root node has instances of type `MyNode` and with data/parameters as specified in the JSON string.

How can I accomplish this? Any pointers would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First call JSON.parse on that string, then call a recursive function which will create a tree with use of your constructor.

---

**Update:**

```
  var output = parse_constructor(json);
    console.log(output);

    function parse_constructor(input){

       var output = new MyNode();
       output.a1 = input.a1;
       output.a2 = input.a2;

       for(var i in input.children){
           output.children.push(
               parse_constructor(input.children[i])
           );
       }
       return output;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zdeet6v5/1/

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but not by much. If you're not going to demonstrate the details of how to write the function, it would be better as a comment.

Comment: @sitnarf I was just going to modify your original answer because the recursion was failing at first. Your new answer works correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. Works like a charm. :-)